# Forge MeshPhongMaterial transparent color

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, forge

In Forge Viewer I added and I tried to set color for `THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry` to `#384c70` and as Material I used `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()`. But there is a problem because that Color is transparent. If I used the same Color in THREEjs sandbox then it was right without transparent. Where is a problem?
I don't need transparent color. This error is also present for other colors not for all.
Thanks.

There is a example of my code:

```js
this.viewer.overlays.addScene("custom-scene");

let plane = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(100, 100);
let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

material.color = new THREE.Color("#384c70");
material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(plane, material);
mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);

this.viewer.overlays.addMesh(mesh, "custom-scene");
this.viewer.impl.sceneUpdated(true);
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your post since it is not possible to set a color for a geometry. Meaning setting `#384c70` to `THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry` does not make sense.

Comment: Ofcourse, i have created a custom material, type of `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial` and for it i setted color

Comment: And I mean it isn't a problem only THREEjs, but combination THREEjs and FORGE Viewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kind of a weird bug in Forge Viewer when using a certain kind of color in an *overlay*. The reason is - the overlay rendering pipeline uses a custom shader logic for turning a specific range of colors into a see-through selection highlight.

It's definitely something the viewer needs to fix but in the meantime, I'd suggest avoiding the overlays and adding your custom geometry using [ModelBuilder](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/ModelBuilder) instead.